Blender 4.x How to add vertices to a new Hook Modifier using Python?
I've checked the existing StackExchange questions but they seem to refer to Blender 2.79 or earlier.   I'm using Blender 4.2 the API seems to have changed.  I'm trying to use Python to hook curve points to the bones in an armature.   I've gotten as far as adding the modifier and calculating which bone to attach to which point, but I am stumped by this line in the documentation:
vertex_indices_set(indices)

"Validates and assigns the array of vertex indices bound to the modifier.  Parameters:
indices (int array of 64 items in [-inf, inf]) – Vertex Indices"
Do I need to assign all the vertices on the curve to each hook modifier, or one vertex?   How do I determine the "index" of the vertex that I need to assign?  For that matter, what kind of array is this call expecting?   I've managed to crash Blender several times by trying different values.


Do I need to assign all the vertices on the curve to each hook modifier, or one vertex?

It depends on what you want to do and the type of curve you are working with. For a Bézier Curve, assigning the handles doesn't seem necessary. I doubt you would want to assign all vertices. This would cause the whole curve to follow the hook object.

How do I determine the "index" of the vertex that I need to assign?

For a Bézier Curve, the control point and both handles are considered vertices. This means that indices 0, 1, and 2 correspond to the left handle, the point, and the right handle of the first control point, respectively. Note that the curve has a direction. If the second point only should be assigned, the desired index is 4.

For that matter, what kind of array is this call expecting?

It is expecting an int array. Something like the following:
# To assign the index of the second control point
curve_object.modifiers['Hook'].vertex_indices_set((4,))

# To assign the indices of the second control point and its handles
curve_object.modifiers['Hook'].vertex_indices_set((3, 4, 5))


Thank you, this was exactly what I needed!
